# HOw to show custom alert to enable notifications in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, uialertview

Hi in my application i want to enable to push notifications for that i am using one switch.

If i on the switch i am registering for push notifications.
If i off the switch i am unregistering for push notifications.

Now issue is when ever i ON the switch i am getting default alert with OK & Don't Allow buttons. If user select OK app enable the switch in settings for notifications.If user select Don't Allow then unregister for notifications.Now my requirement is after i choose any one option above and again user try to enable/disable notifications i have to ask user enable/disable notifications in settings for this i want to show alert. I am not getting properly where i have to write code to behave my app like what i expected. Please help me.

When i launch app i am setting switch state (ON/OFF)based on device token (storing device token in userdefaults).

Thanks please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You  can show your custom alert when user swtich on/off in settings.In your custom alert there should be YES/NO button along with appropriate title and message and if when user choose any option from there then you run your code for taking push  notification permission.

Comment: Hi thanks for ur quick response. Now ON / OFF is in my app not in settings.Can you please let me know how to do that.

Comment: Read your switch state from user default when app is launched, and show your alert  accordingly.